# How do I create a numpy recarray of arbitrary functions?

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy

I am creating a `numpy.recarray` as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array((1., 2.), dtype = [('alpha', np.float, 'beta', np.float)])
arr = np.view(np.recarray)
```

How would I do this if instead of `np.floats` `alpha` and `beta` referred to arbitrary functions?

Comment: What would it mean for a dtype to be an arbitrary function? If one of the dtypes was `print` (using `from __future__ import print_function` to have that as a function), what would you expect to happen, and how would you interact with the resulting array?

Comment: Also, that's not a recarray.

Comment: In that case one would be able to access the `print` function via `arr.print` and for instance print 'foo' to the screen via `arr.print('foo')` that is the only functionality I require here.

Comment: I don't see why you'd want to use a recarray for that.

Comment: I agree it doesn't seem very logical. In short I have some code that I am trying to modify to suit my needs. Unfortunately the last coder seemed to like `np.recarray` (or whatever these constructs are)... a lot and it just so happens that if I can get this functionality using `np.recarray` it will save me re writing a lot of code...

Comment: You'd need `arr.view(np.recarray)`, not `np.view(np.recarray)`, to get a recarray out of that. (I stupidly overlooked that line the first time I read the question.) Anyway, while you could specify `object` instead of `np.float`, that wouldn't do what you want; `arr.alpha` or `arr.beta` would produce a 0-dimensional array containing the function, rather than the actual function. (The same thing happens with float dtypes.)

Comment: Ah thanks for the catch. I think an array containing the function will suffice for now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `np.object` dtype can contain any Python object, including functions.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

lmb = lambda: "help, I'm trapped in an array!"
arr = np.array([(max, lmb)], dtype=[('alpha', np.object), ('beta', np.object)])
arr = arr.view(np.recarray)

print(repr(arr))
# array([(<built-in function max>, <function <lambda> at 0x63992a8>)], 
#       dtype=[('alpha', 'O'), ('beta', 'O')]).view(numpy.recarray)

print(arr.alpha[0](1, 2))
# 2

print(arr.beta[0]())
# help, I'm trapped in an array!
```

The extra set of square brackets around the tuple of functions was added in order to force the array to be one-dimensional, which allows you to index the first row in order to access the functions it contains.

It's a bit more awkward to access the functions if you allow the array to be 0-dimensional, but it's still possible, as user2357112 pointed out in the comments below:

```
arr2 = np.array((max, lmb), dtype=[('alpha', np.object), ('beta', np.object)])
arr2 = arr2.view(np.recarray)

print(repr(arr2))
# array((<built-in function max>, <function <lambda> at 0x63995f0>), 
#       dtype=[('alpha', 'O'), ('beta', 'O')]).view(numpy.recarray)

print(repr(arr2['alpha']))
# array(<built-in function max>, dtype=object)

# we can't access the function without any indexing, because `arr2['alpha']` 
# is still an ndarray containing a function, rather than a plain function,
# and arrays have no `.__call__()` method:

arr2.alpha(1, 2)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-100-dc1bd6446de4> in <module>()
# ----> 1 arr2['alpha'](1, 2)

# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

# it is possible to access the function by indexing with an empty tuple
print(arr2.alpha[()](1, 2))
# 2
```

There were a couple of other syntax issues in your example that I've fixed here.

- Your `dtype=` argument should contain a separate `(name, dtype)` tuple for each field, rather than a single long tuple.
- `.view` is a method of an ndarray, not a standalone function.

I do have to ask why you want to do this, though. A simple `dict` seems like a much more appropriate data structure.

Comment: "It seems to be necessary to create the empty array first, then fill in the fields with the functions." - that's probably related to the fact that you're creating a 1-dimensional array of length 1, while the original code seems to create a 0-dimensional array.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, it's actually necessary to create a 1-dimensional array in order to call the function (see my update)

Comment: Not quite; you can get the same effect with a 0-dimensional array and `arr.alpha[()]` or `arr.alpha[...]` instead of `arr.alpha[0]`.

Comment: Good point, although `arr2.alpha[...]` does not work, since it also returns an array rather than the function it contains

Comment: What the - I could have sworn `[...]` was supposed to do the conversion, but it looks like only `[()]` does the job. I remember trying `[...]` and having it work before.

Comment: This does the job thanks very much and also for the catches. See my dialogue with @user2357112 above as to why I need to use `np.recarray`

Comment: @fen OK, but I still find it hard to believe that putting functions inside recarrays is what you really want to do. Is your goal, by any chance, just to have `object.name()` syntax? If so then it would be trivial to write a Python class that will serve your needs.

Comment: @ali_m Now I have a quick solution I'll stick with that for this particular project but if you're willing to offer some advice here on writing a class to provide the `object.name()` syntax then feel free I'd be very interested to learn.

Comment: @fen SO isn't really the right place for extended guides/tutorials, but there are lots of them available if you Google something like "object oriented Python". [Here's one which looks fairly decent](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/06/18/improve-your-python-python-classes-and-object-oriented-programming/).

Answer (score 0):

From the clarification in the comments, this doesn't sound like a job for a recarray. In Python 3, you'd want [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace); in Python 2, you could implement it yourself pretty easily:

```
class Namespace(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

namespace = Namespace(func1=print, func2=len, func3=sum)

namespace.func1(namespace.func2([1, 2])) # prints 2
```